# Merge multiple spark rows inside dataframe by ID into one row based on update_time

Tags: pyspark

we need to merge multiple rows based on ID into a single record using Pyspark. If there are multiple updates to the column, then we have to select the one with the last update made to it.
Please note, NULL would mean there was no update made to the column in that instance.
So, basically we have to create a single row with the consolidated updates made to the records.
So,for example, if this is the dataframe ...

Looking for similar answer, but in Pyspark .. [Merge rows in a spark scala Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466270/merge-rows-in-a-spark-scala-dataframe)

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id       | column1          | column2         | updated_at |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 123      | update1          | <*no-update*>   | 1634228709 |   
| 123      | <*no-update*>    | 80              | 1634228724 |
| 123      | update2          | <*no-update*>   | 1634229000 |
```

expected output is -

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id       | column1          | column2       | updated_at |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 123      | update2          | 80            | 1634229000 |
```

Comment: Why is column2 80 in  the result. Isnt it supposed to be NULL, if you want the data from the latest update. Or are there more rules

Comment: @Emerson sorry for the confusion. NULL would actually mean there was no update done to the column in that row.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that our input dataframe is:

```
+---+-------+----+----------+
|id |col1   |col2|updated_at|
+---+-------+----+----------+
|123|null   |null|1634228709|
|123|null   |80  |1634228724|
|123|update2|90  |1634229000|
|12 |update1|null|1634221233|
|12 |null   |80  |1634228333|
|12 |update2|null|1634221220|
+---+-------+----+----------+
```

What we want is to covert `updated_at` to `TimestampType` then order by `id` and `updated_at` in `desc` order:

```py
df = df.withColumn("updated_at", F.col("updated_at").cast(TimestampType())).orderBy(
        F.col("id"), F.col("updated_at").desc()
    )
```

that gives us:

```
+---+-------+----+-------------------+
|id |col1   |col2|updated_at         |
+---+-------+----+-------------------+
|12 |null   |80  |2021-10-14 18:18:53|
|12 |update1|null|2021-10-14 16:20:33|
|12 |update2|null|2021-10-14 16:20:20|
|123|update2|90  |2021-10-14 18:30:00|
|123|null   |80  |2021-10-14 18:25:24|
|123|null   |null|2021-10-14 18:25:09|
+---+-------+----+-------------------+
```

Now get first non `None` value in each column or return `None` and group by `id`:

```py
exp = [F.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in df.columns[1:]]
df = df.groupBy(F.col("id")).agg(*exp)
```

And the result is:

```
+---+-------+----+-------------------+
|id |col1   |col2|updated_at         |
+---+-------+----+-------------------+
|123|update2|90  |2021-10-14 18:30:00|
|12 |update1|80  |2021-10-14 18:18:53|
+---+-------+----+-------------------+
```

Here's the full example code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
    data = [
        (123, None, None, 1634228709),
        (123, None, 80, 1634228724),
        (123, "update2", 90, 1634229000),
        (12, "update1", None, 1634221233),
        (12, None, 80, 1634228333),
        (12, "update2", None, 1634221220),
    ]
    columns = ["id", "col1", "col2", "updated_at"]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
    df = df.withColumn("updated_at", F.col("updated_at").cast(TimestampType())).orderBy(
        F.col("id"), F.col("updated_at").desc()
    )
    exp = [F.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in df.columns[1:]]
    df = df.groupBy(F.col("id")).agg(*exp)
```